# 'CONCATENATE' Query workaround - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation

I am trying to create a custom string by concatenating certain columns and "_" together. I would like this ideally to be within a query function, but I know this isn't possible with CONCATENATE has
anyone got any experience on how to replicate this?

I would like to combine A,B,C where K 'YES'

Thank you :)

I have used standard IF's where A="","",else...  but I don't want a load of blank formulas sat in the book.

Answer (score 0):

Use FILTER.

```
=FILTER(A2:A&B2:B&C2:C,K2:K="Yes")
```